# Как сделать прокрутку фотографий

Tags: javascript, css, python, html5, css-animation

Возник вопрос с прокруткой фотографий на сайте. Я имею виду, чтобы на сайте фотографии прокручивались автоматически. К примеру вот  сайт - [https://yeezy-moscow.ru/?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Poisk&utm_content=7634667291&utm_term=yeezy%20boost%20купить&yclid=3403969441023948758](https://yeezy-moscow.ru/?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Poisk&utm_content=7634667291&utm_term=yeezy%20boost%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&yclid=3403969441023948758)

Всем, за ранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVxyTOPPEPc). Там все понятно объясняется, но только тебе нужно немного изменить код. Убрать лишние кнопки и сделать, чтобы объекты менялись по порядку через N количество времени.

Comment: Вот [еще пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwiR2lasSlo). Перед тем, как писать вопрос, смотри примеры в интернете. Это экономит твое время и наше!